I have a dataset with 18 biomarker features and a target variable. I want to find the features which are having the biggest impact on the target
I Have some disease biomarker datasets that contain 18 biomarker readings from different samples and a target variable which shows presence or absence of disease (features are both categorical and numerical). I want to see if only using the features which have the biggest impact on the target variable will improve performance of my predictive models - currently using scikit learn.
here are some of the specifics of the data etc.

These are liver disease datasets I have, 4 of them. They all contain the same 18 biomarker features, which include readings such as "Albumin level", "total cholesterol", "sex", "triglyceride" etc.

2.Target variable is binary for "0" = no liver disease, "1" = Liver disease.

I have a discovery dataset I am using for training and 3 validation datasets which I am using for testing. so accuracy metrics based on correct prediction of disease in validation sets.

I have tried applying shallow models including logistic regression, gradient boosting and random forest using the 18 biomarkers, as well as an MLP. datasets are quite unbalanced and not performing as well as I hoped, especially for predicting group 1. - This is why I thought feature selection could help in reducing noise.

I have tried a random forest approach to see how much each feature decreases the impurity of the split - though given I am quite inexperienced, I don't know if this is the best approach.


Can anyone advise on how would be a good way to do this?
Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Cross Validated.  Most of us run into this question and there are innumerable ways of attacking it.  Can you say more about what you are inclined to try, or have tried?

The more details you provide about the specific situation you face, the more likely you are to get a useful answer. This is very vague about the nature and timing of biomarker readings and disease presence/absence. If biomarkers were measured after disease diagnosis, they won't necessarily be predictive at all in practice. How are you planning on applying your model in the future? Also, the number of cases in both disease presence/absence can be important. Please edit the question to address those matters, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

First, avoid feature selection. That's particularly true for binary regression models, as omitting any outcome-associated predictor from the model leads to bias in estimates for the included predictors.
Second, unless you have many thousands of cases in your data sets, the train/test split approach loses both precision in training and power for testing. As suggested in that link, model all the data together (accounting for the different data sets) and test the modeling approach with bootstrapping.
Third, unbalanced data sets aren't a problem per se. Yes, you are limited by the number of cases in the minority outcome class. Other than that, it's a matter of how well the predictors can be used to estimate the probability of class membership.
Fourth, you are using accuracy to evaluate model performance. That's not a good idea even with balanced classes; it becomes worse with imbalance. Further complicating things, I suspect that you are using the (often hidden) default of 0.5 model-estimated probability cutoff to assign class assignments and test performance. The choice of cutoff should be based on relative costs of different positive and negative class assignments after you have a well calibrated model of class probability as a function of predictors. See this page. Use a strictly proper scoring rule to evaluate your model.
Fifth, standard approaches like logistic regression can often work well. They might not if there are unknown (and unmodeled) interactions among predictors in terms of their associations with outcome. A gradient-boosted model can help capture such hidden interactions (even if it's hard to interpret the model later). I was going to suggest that until I re-read your question and saw that you had already tried it. Maybe try again with the above points in mind; make sure that the model learns slowly.
Sixth, your predictors just might not be adequate to make the class distinctions that you wish. There might be biological and clinical bases for that, as some biomarkers might be altered from normal values in individuals who might be at risk for liver disease that hasn't yet been diagnosed, and biomarkers most specific for liver disease wouldn't typically be measured in individuals not suspected of that disease (and thus might not be in your data sets).
Finally, there's an important issue about how you will use the model (if it's not just for self-study). It seems that what one might want in practice is a model that will predict whether someone will develop liver disease. What you are modeling is whether someone has already been diagnosed with it.
